# CSV replace quotes with their HTML code using regex

Tags: regex, csv

I am parsing a CSV file and there are extra quotes in between the field value. So I tried replacing those like this:

```
regex = '([^,"\r\n])\\?"([^,"\r\n])'
```

This was working fine but I came across a file in which the quotes were like:

```
"text","text\" \"text","text "ab" text","text"
```

So the output came like: `"text","text&quot; \&quot;text","text &quot;ab&quot;","text"` as the space has been captured previously.

**Desired Output:**

```
"text","text&quot; &quot;text","text &quot;ab&quot;","text"
```

I can't use **lookbehinds** as it is not supported.

Is there any other possible solution for this?

Comment: You could do it in 3 stages, replace "," with <DELIMITER>, replace " with &quot; and then replace <DELIMITER> with "," again

Comment: @TimRadcliffe Yes, that can be possible. But I am trying to fix it in one replace.

Comment: Can you use look-aheads? I hope you do.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes. I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to such a regular expression:

```
([^,\r\n\\])\\?"(?=[^,\r\n])
```

To be replaced with `$1&quot;`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mC1iO4/3)

Sample input-output:

```
  "text","text\" \"text","text "ab" text","text"
->"text","text&quot; &quot;text","text &quot;ab&quot; text","text"

  "text","text\" \"text","text text "ab"",""ab" text"
->"text","text&quot; &quot;text","text text &quot;ab&quot;","&quot;ab&quot; text"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Stribizhev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778459/csv-replace-quotes-with-their-html-code-using-regex/30779208#30779208) was working fine for my question. But while testing I found a case where the data was like this:

```
"text","text\" \"text","text "ab" text","text "dasd"
",
```

So to overcome this I updated the above answer like this:

```
([^,"\r\n\\])(\\?")([^,\\"\n\r]+)\2(?=[^"]?)
```

To be replaced with:

```
$1&quot;$3&quot;
```

And it captured all cases for me.

Here is the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mC1iO4/4).